Extract the xpath following child node with condition

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
>     
>       
> <a:Passengers>
>     <a:Passenger>
>       <a:PaxID>Ynr92+G9wmewELJS5SyMUmb3XHEefPUif4OXTIstk3N3yvtldxscrvgvygd9QHlH</a:PaxID>
>       <a:PersonOrgId>80553253</a:PersonOrgId>
>       <a:Ptc>ADT </a:Ptc>
>       <a:PtcGroup>ADT </a:PtcGroup>
>       <a:PtcId>1</a:PtcId>
>       <a:RecordLocator/>
>       <a:RecordNum>1</a:RecordNum>
>       <a:RedressId>8778787878</a:RedressId>
>       <a:ResSegStatus>4</a:ResSegStatus>
>       <a:Row>22</a:Row>
>       <a:Seat>B</a:Seat>
>       <a:Services xmlns:b="charges.radixx.com/v1">
>             <b:Charge>
>               <b:Amount>0</b:Amount>
>   </a:Passenger>
> </a:Passengers>
> 
>   
>   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Want to extract the Xpath of PaxID with Amount ='0'
Here condition is in next node parallel to PaxID in a child node.
Xpath ://Passengers/Passenger/Services/Charge[1][Amount='0']/PaxID tried but not worked. Please help me xpath Query

On jmeter documentation

NAMESPACES As a work-round for namespace limitations of the Xalan
XPath parser (implementation on which JMeter is based) you need to:
provide a Properties file (if for example your file is named
namespaces.properties) which contains mappings for the namespace
prefixes: prefix1=http://foo.apache.org
prefix2=http://toto.apache.org … reference this file in
user.properties file using the property:
xpath.namespace.config=namespaces.properties

First lets make your xml-file valid like this
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <d:RetrievePaxAndSeatsByFlightResponse xmlns:d="departurecontrol.YYZ.com/v1">
      <d:RetrievePaxAndSeatsByFlightResult>
        <a:Passengers xmlns:a="passengers.YYZ.com/v1">
          <a:Passenger>
            <a:PaxID>Ynr92+G9wmewELJS5SyMUmb3XHEefPUif4OXTIstk3N3yvtldxscrvgvygd9QHlH</a:PaxID>
            <a:PersonOrgId>80553253</a:PersonOrgId>
            <a:Ptc>ADT </a:Ptc>
            <a:PtcGroup>ADT </a:PtcGroup>
            <a:PtcId>1</a:PtcId>
            <a:RecordLocator/>
            <a:RecordNum>1</a:RecordNum>
            <a:RedressId>8778787878</a:RedressId>
            <a:ResSegStatus>4</a:ResSegStatus>
            <a:Row>22</a:Row>
            <a:Seat>B</a:Seat>
            <a:Services>
              <b:Charge xmlns:b="charges.radixx.com/v1">
                <b:Amount>0</b:Amount>
              </b:Charge>
            </a:Services>
          </a:Passenger>
        </a:Passengers>
      </d:RetrievePaxAndSeatsByFlightResult>
    </d:RetrievePaxAndSeatsByFlightResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

And then create/change namespaces.properties file with these entries:
s=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
d=departurecontrol.YYZ.com/v1
a=passengers.YYZ.com/v1
b=charges.radixx.com/v1

And then use this XPath
 //a:Passengers/a:Passenger[a:Services/b:Charge/b:Amount='0']/a:PaxID

Where we create a predicate on a:Passenger where a:Services/b:Charge/b:Amount='0'
